# Having problems while trying to delete single rows from a custom ToDo list?

Tags: android, android-fragments, checkbox, android-studio

I want to delete selected rows from a todo list by clicking on the checkbox and deleting them trough the delete button, for that I am within my custom adapter setting a `setOnCheckedChangeListener` on my checkbox and `setOnClickListener` on my delete button, now keep in mind that the delete button is inflated on my fragment view and I am using it on my row view, but the problem is only the last element from my todo list is getting deleted not the rest of them, I tried working within the fragment view and notify the adapter later on but all I got was a null pointer error on my checkbox.

Row View:

```
todoCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.todo_CheckBox);

    todoTextView.setText(values.get(position));

    todoCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), " CheckBox Status: " + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            mDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (mDelete.isPressed() && (todoCheckBox.isChecked())) {

                     //convertView.clearFocus(position);
                     mAdapter.clear();
                     //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Fragment View:

```
@TargetApi(9) // remember this for isEmpty()
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_todo, container, false);

ArrayList<String> todoList = new ArrayList<String>();
mAdapter = new UsersAdapter(getActivity(), todoList);
listViewToDo = (ListView) v.findViewById (android.R.id.list);
listViewToDo.setAdapter(mAdapter);

mToDoField = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.todo_editText);
mDelete = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);

mAdd = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
mAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        String toDo = mToDoField.getText().toString().trim();

        if (toDo.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }

        mAdapter.add(toDo);

        mToDoField.setText("");
    }
});

return v;
}
}
```

Comment: It's going to be tough with just using a `ArrayList<String>`.  You should create a custom class that has at least the String and the current state of the checkbox for that row.  Otherwise, how will you keep checked items checked if the app quits and re-starts?  Once you make that change, deleting rows that are checked will be much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign an onclick listener to your delete button outside of the onChecked statement.  Add it in code just after you assign the onClick event to the add button.  This is because a view in android can only have 1 listener per event type.

The onClick event can look something like below using a sparese

```
mDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            SparseBooleanArray checked = listViewToDo.getCheckedItemPositions();
            for (int i = 0; i < listViewToDo.getCount(); i++){

                if (checked.get(i)==true)
                {
                     mAdapter.remove(i);

                } 
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

            }
             listViewToDo.clearChoices();               
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you give an example please?